# psr-4 autoloading not working in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, psr-4

I'm trying to create a directory to store custom classes, so I create the directory `app/ArgumentClub/Transformers`, and the class `UserTransformer.php` in that folder.

I then autoload with:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "ArgumentClub\\": "app/ArgumentClub"
    }
},
```

And run `composer dump-autoload`. And namespace like this:

```
<?php namespace ArgumentClub\Transformers;

class UserTransformer {
```

I'm calling this class within another class like this:

```
<?php

use Sorskod\Larasponse\Larasponse;
use ArgumentClub\Transformers;

class UsersController extends \BaseController {

    ...

    $transformed = $this->fractal->collection($users, new UserTransformer());
```

But I get the error:

```
Class 'UserTransformer' not found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are you calling the class? Also, `UserTransfomer` is either a typo in your question, or a typo in your code.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've updated my question to show where I call the `UserTransformer` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the `use` correctly.

`use ArgumentClub\Transformers;` imports that Namespace, but doesn't import the class you want to use.

To fix it you can either extend the `use` statement (which you should) to be like so:

```
use ArgumentClub\Transformers\UserTransformer
```

Or you can add the Transformers namespace to where you instantiate your UserTransformer class

```
$transformed = $this->fractal->collection($users, new Transformers\UserTransformer());
```

When you want to instantiate a namespaced class without putting the full namespace, you need to put the full class path in the `use` statement.